# how get all elements from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have an array containing different types (numbers , string , array) and im trying to write a code that makes them all in one array (get the elements of the inner array to a new array) with recursive function

example :
`let a = [1,2,3,[4,5,6],'abc',['e','f'] ]`

output :  `"1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n'abc'\n'e'\n'f'"`

im using this function

```
function date(inp) {
    let z = ''
    if (inp.length == 0) {
        return z
    }
    else {
        let input = inp[0];
        if (typeof (input) == 'string') {
            return `${z}\n${input}\n${aa(inp.slice(1))}`;
        }
        else if (typeof (input) == 'number') {
            return `${z}\n${input}\n${aa(inp.slice(1))}`;        }
        else if (typeof (input) == 'object') {
            let a = ''
            for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                a = `${a}\n${input[i]}`
            }
            return `${z}\n${a}\n${aa(inp.slice(1))}`;
        }
    }
}
```

but the result was wrong : `\n1\n\n2\n\n3\n\n\n4\n5\n6\n\n'abc'\n\n\n'e'\n'f'\n`

how to fix it

Comment: `[1,2,3,[4,5,6],'abc',['e','f'] ].flat().join('\n')`

Comment: You seem to be trying to invent [`Arrayp.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Comment: what about `flat`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Comment: @HassanImam not quite. That doesn't yield quoted strings. Assuming the stated output is actually what is needed.

Comment: Array.flat().join(\n) worked correctly .. thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

You can use `flat(Infinity)` or recursive function as shown in the code.
Inside the recursive function iterate the input array and in callback check if the current element is an array. If so then recursively call the function or push the element to the `flatArr`

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6,[11,12,13]], 'abc', ['e', 'f']]

function date(inp, flatArr = []) {
  inp.forEach((item) => {
    if (Array.isArray(item)) {
      return date(item, flatArr)
    } 
     flatArr.push(item)
    
  })
  return flatArr.join('\n');
};

console.log(date(a))
```

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6], 'abc', ['e', 'f']].flat(Infinity).join('\n');
console.log(a)
```